# java (autocomplete) multiple selection/values in textfield

Tags: java, autocomplete, textfield

I am working on a project where I need to implement a Component that provides an "autocomplete multiple selection" function.

Sure, I read a lot of tutorial and viewed lots of examples but I did not find anything to solve my problem. The last days I was searching and searching and finally the best component I have seen was this one:

[image: Primefaces autocomplete multiple selection]

Stackoverflow supports this kind of function as well when you ask a new question and have to specify the tags you want.
But this is css and Java is not able to handle "complex" css stylesheets. :/

So, I wonder if this can be done with pure Java.

If not, it would be really enough to have a textfield (or another field?) that includes different components to separate different inputs as shown in the picture. This is exact what I need.

**A field that includes components which can be removed by clicking on "X"**

But I am not sure if this can be solved with Java.
I need a way to separate different inputs in a textfield (or another component?) like adding a border around texts.
It sounds easy but I guess it can be really tricky. . .

Does anyone have any suggestions? or ideas how I can solve my problem?
I would really appreciate it because I ran out of ideas.

URL to PrimeFaces: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/autoCompleteMultiple.jsf

Ioannis K.

Comment: How does the Prime Faces solution fall short?

Comment: I am not using PrimeFaces. Just working with Swing.. and wonder whether I can build a similar field with pure java (without html/css/js..) that I can use in my desktop application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everybody who is interested in a solution:

http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/component-border/

Instead of adding a single button you are able to add a panel containing multiple buttons.
Play a bit around with the settings and voilà!

Answer (score 0):

The swing demo of Alice In Wonderland introduces components in a JTextPane/JEditorPane. It probably suffices to add a clickable image before a space and do a bit of coloring.

The alternative would be to add in a edit box like panel a list of components where at the end is a JTextField that on space/focus lost turns into your blue component, and creates a new JTextField.

Comment: I hoped to avoid this kind of solution. To start, I need a JPanel. The first component in this panel would be a "TextField with autocomplete function". When selecting a list element (save) - a new Component (e.g. JLabel) is being created inside this Panel.

Does an "easier" solution exist? Building everything manually would be my worst case.

Comment: You have a very specific scenario. I hope someone else encountered some solution, but this is typically DIY.

Comment: I hoped that somebody did something similar because this is a really nice-to-have feature. Or whether somebody could give me some ideas how to implement it.

Acutually I have a JPanel. In this JPanel there is a textfield with autocomplete function where you are able to select elements in a jlist. When you select an element, it appears in a button wihin the JPanel. I can remove the element by simply pressing the button.

This solution is a roundabout way.